# Compiler won't let me return object using ternary operator

Tags: c#, object, compiler-errors, ternary-operator

I attempted to return the array "**arr**" of the type according to the input object type which can be either a `string[]` or a `string`

```
public static object custom_return(object ob, string[] arr)
{
    return ob.GetType() == typeof(string) ? arr[0] : arr;
}
```

This code will not compile because

> ErrorCS0173   Type of conditional expression cannot be determined
>   because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and
>   'string[]'

yet if broken up

```
    public static object custom_return(object ob, string[] arr)
    {
        if (ob.GetType() == typeof(string))
            return arr[0];
        else
            return arr;
    }
```

It's no problem at all. Why is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because in a ternary operator, the second type must match (implicitly or explicitly) the first one (or vice-versa).

It works if you do:

```
return ob.GetType() == typeof(string) ? (object)arr[0] : arr;
```

Because then `string[]` can be converted implicitly to `object`

The opposite (*casting `string[]` to `object`*) would also work

The type matching between the two members in the ternary operator is evaluated before it's assigned to the result, so in your case, it gives the error before it even knows it's going to be assigned to an `object` (so it doesn't infer that both types should be able to be implicitly converted to `object`)

Note that (this is subjective and oppinionated), *I* prefer to have an `if/else` when the types do not match (I tend to think of a ternary expression as a "single value"). To me, it makes the code more readable and less prone to errors.

Answer (score 2):

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

And in your case, no implicit conversion exists between `string` and `string[]`.

Comment: Is there a logical explanation why? Since it doesnt actually convert the types. it cant be about type safety considering they are turned into an **object**. so a conversion form string or string[] to object always exists